# Using the squeezing theorem to prove continuity at $(0,0)$

Tags: inequality, continuity

The piecewise function $f(x, y)$  is defined as follows:

$$
f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{x^2y^3 + 3y^6}{x^2 + y^4}, & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0), \\
    0, & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0).
\end{cases}
$$

Using the AG-inequality I concluded that:

\begin{aligned}
    0 &\leq \frac{|x^2y^3 + 3y^6|}{|x^2 + y^4|} \\
    &\leq \frac{|x^2y^3|}{2|xy^2|} + \frac{3|y^6|}{2|xy^2|} 
\end{aligned}

The first term approaches $0$ as $x$ and $y$ both approach $0$ but what is there to do with the second term?

Comment: AM-GM inequality, 1/2*(a+b)>=sqrt(a*b)

Comment: Nothing can be done about the second term: by all means $\limsup\limits_{(x,y)\to 0}\left\lvert \frac{y^4}{x}\right\rvert=\infty$, and the same holds for the bound you've found.

Answer (score 2):

***Disclaimer:** I'm not a native English speaker and I'm not familiar with conventional English names for mathematical objects.*

I'd like to suggest a different approach, supposing you only need to show continuity and you aren't forced to follow a fixed path (e.g. "use this theorem to...") in the exercise, since I can't find a clear and rigorous way to use the squeezing theorem. I hope more skilled mathematicians will provide insights on that side as well.

If the problem allows it, let's change our variables $(x,y)$ into polar coordinates $(\rho,\theta)$:

\begin{align*}
x &= \rho \cos\theta \\
y &= \rho \sin\theta
\end{align*}

This way, the nonzero part of your function becomes:

\begin{align*}
f_1(\rho,\theta) &= \frac{\rho^5\cos^2\theta\sin^3\theta+3\rho^6\sin^6\theta}{\rho^2\cos^2\theta + \rho^4 \sin^4 \theta} \\
&= \frac{\rho^5 \left( \cos^2\theta \sin^3\theta + 3\rho \sin^6\theta \right)}{\rho^2\left( \cos^2\theta+\rho^2\sin^4\theta \right)} \\
&= \frac{\rho^3 \left( \cos^2\theta \sin^3\theta + 3\rho \sin^6\theta \right)}{\cos^2\theta+\rho^2\sin^4\theta}
\end{align*}

Now, our new condition to show continuity in $0$ is that $f_1(\rho,\theta)\to 0$ as $\rho \to 0$ for any value of $\theta$. Consider the new form of the limit you needed:

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{\rho\to 0} f_1(\rho,\theta) = \lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac{\rho^3 \left( \cos^2\theta \sin^3\theta + 3\rho \sin^6\theta \right)}{\cos^2\theta+\rho^2\sin^4\theta} = 0
\end{equation*}

This is true for any value of $\theta$, as requested, because $\rho^3$ at the numerator is dominating (meaning it is the term that tends to zero more quickly) and we don't have any problems with continuity, except for one case: $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

For this last value of $\theta$, we have $\cos\theta=0$, which may be an issue since the denominator would tend to zero. Moreover, note that:

\begin{align*}
\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi &\implies \sin\theta=1 \\
\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2} + k\pi &\implies \sin\theta=-1
\end{align*}

However, this won't be a problem, as shown below. Let's have a look at the function for $\cos\theta = 0$:

\begin{align*}
f_1(\rho,\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi) &= \frac{\rho^3 (3\rho)}{\rho^2} \\
&= 3\rho^2 \\
\implies f_1(\rho,\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi) &\to 0 \text{ for } \rho\to 0 \\
\end{align*}

Hence, $\lim_{\rho\to 0} f_1 = 0$ for every value of $\theta$. This indeed proves that your function is continuous in $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $((x_k,y_k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(0,0)$ and assume without loss of generality that $|x_k|,|y_k|<1$ for all $k$. Define $u_k:=\max\{|x_k|,|y_k|\}$ for all $k$. Then
\begin{align*}
0\leq\frac{|x_k^2y_k^3+3y_k^6|}{|x_k^2+y_k^4|}&\leq\frac{u_k^5+3u_k^6}{u_k^4}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0.
\end{align*}
So we have shown that for an arbitrary null sequence $((x_k,y_k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ we have $f(x_k,y_k)\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. This implies that $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$.